# VSTS 2013 server access using REST API

Tags: azure-devops

How i can access my VSTS 2013 server using REST API? Is there REST API interfaces are defined by VSTS?
I have researched abou this, but did not fined any good reference.

Comment: code tags and spellings

Comment: Do you clear it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TFS 2013 does not have REST APIs available. Upgrade to a modern version of TFS or migrate to Visual Studio Team Services in order to enable REST APIs.